# how to compile c++ in release mode with vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml

so i am making a game using c++ and sfml and we all know that debug mode is slow so I need to know how to build my game in release mode
this is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and this is my MakeFile:

```
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -Isrc/include -c coding/main.cpp

link:
    g++ main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: Unclear. What is your question exactly? Maybe you should read some of this, to understand how things work over here: [ask]

Comment: Possibly add `-O3` to your compiler arguments: [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: Looks like you need 2 `"configurations"` sections one called `"Win32-debug"` and the other called `"Win32-release"` and then change the flags in the release one.

Comment: Your makefile provides only a single configuration. There's no option to actually add debug info there: no `-g` option is present or can be added. I recommend going with CMake in which case the only thing that needed to be changed would be passing `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` or `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` during the configuration. Afaik VS Code does provide cmake support...

Answer (score 0):

```
@OUTSEET
Proceed your steps as per other's comments.
I thought of sharing my updated Makefile:
```

```
all:
    @if [[ ! -f main.o ]];\
    then\
        make main.o;\
    else\
        ls -tr main.o coding/main.cpp 2>&1 |\
        tail -1 |\
        grep "main.o" >/dev/null 2>&1;\
        if [[ 0 -eq $$? ]];\
        then\
            echo main.o is up to date;\
        else\
            if [[ -f main.o ]];\
            then\
                echo "Removing main.o due to updated coding/main.cpp";\
                echo rm main.o;\
                rm main.o;\
            fi;\
            make main.o;\
        fi;\
        if [[ ! -f main ]];\
        then\
            make main;\
        else\
            echo "main.exe is up to date";\
        fi;\
    fi
#BETTER TO USE -O3 DURING RELEASE.
main.o:
    @echo "g++ -Isrc/include -O3 -c coding/main.cpp -o main.o";\
    g++ -O3 -Isrc/include -c coding/main.cpp -o main.o;\
    if [[ ! -f main ]];\
    then\
        make main;\
    else\
        ls -tr main.o main.cpp main 2>&1 |\
        tail -1 |\
        grep "main$$" >/dev/null 2>&1;\
        if [[ 0 -eq $$? ]];\
        then\
            echo main is up to date;\
        else\
            if [[ -f main ]];\
            then\
                echo "Removing main.o due to updated cpp or obj files";\
                echo rm main;\
                rm main;\
            fi;\
            make main;\
        fi;\
    fi
main:
    @echo "g++ -O3 main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system";\
    g++ -O3 main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
#I HAVE WRITTEN THIS MAKEFILE USING CYGWIN
#YOU CAN REPLACE main.exe TO main WHEN USING OTHER OPERATING SYSTEMS AT OTHER UNIVERSE :) => FOR MY FUN.
clean:
    @CLEANUPTODATE="y";\
    for cleanfiles in main.o \
    main.exe;\
    do\
        if [[ -f "$$cleanfiles" ]];\
        then\
            echo "rm $$cleanfiles";\
            rm "$$cleanfiles";\
            CLEANUPTODATE=$$?;\
        fi;\
    done;\
    if [[ "y" = "$$CLEANUPTODATE" ]];\
    then\
        echo "make clean is up to date";\
    fi
    Sample output from localhost:
        $ make
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    g++ -Isrc/include -O3 -c coding/main.cpp -o main.o
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    g++ -O3 main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    $ make clean
    rm main.o
    rm main.exe
    $ make clean
    make clean is up to date
    $ make
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    g++ -Isrc/include -O3 -c coding/main.cpp -o main.o
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    g++ -O3 main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/murugesan.openssl/'
    $ make
    main.o is up to date
    main.exe is up to date
```